# a cash register object that simulates a real life cash register - Java

Tags: java, methods, transactions

I need to program a cash register that can perform transactions.

A transaction has the following steps: 
(1) The transaction starts when the customer decides to purchase an item for a given price.

(2) The customer give the cashier a certain amount of money in bills and coins.

(3) The cashier calculates the exact change. The change is
calculated so that the total number of bills and coins given to the customer is minimized.

(4) The cashier gives the customer their change and the remaining
bills and coins are added to the register.
If the transaction must be cancelled for any reason, the cash
register returns to the state before the transaction began.

According to Web-Cat, 85% of my coding is correct. I am really struggling with the last part of my code which include `public void completePurchase()` and `public static String prettyPrint(int amount) { }`. My instructor has included small descriptions above all the methods.

I really hope that you can help me with these two methods. Certainly, I am not asking for solutions, but help to solve the problem.

The first class includes the cashregister.class. And the second class is a Junittester.

```
> public class CashRegister
{

    // ==========================================================
    // Constants
    // ==========================================================

    /** The value of a dollar (100 cents) */
    public static final int DOLLAR       = 100;
    /** The value of a quarter (25 cents) */
    public static final int QUARTER      = 25;
    /** The value of a dime (10 cents) */
    public static final int DIME         = 10;
    /** The value of a nickel (5 cents) */
    public static final int NICKEL       = 5;
    /** The value of a penny (1 cent) */
    public static final int PENNY        = 1;

    // ==========================================================
    // Fields
    // ==========================================================

    private int             purchasePrice;

    private int[]           registerMoney;
    private int[]           paymentMoney = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private int[]           changeMoney  = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    private int             transactionCount;                // number of
// transactions
    private int             transactionTotal;                // number of cents
// that I have made from transactions


    // ==========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ==========================================================
    /**
     * Creates a new CashRegister object with the specified money in it. If the
     * specified money array is not valid, an IllegalArgumentException is
     * thrown. The money array is not valid if: - the length of the array is
     * anything but 5 - the array contains a negative number in any of the cells
     * - the array contains a 0 in _all_ of its cells /**
     * 
     * @param money
     *            the money that will go into the new cash register
     */
    public CashRegister(int[] money)

    {
        if (this.moneyHasNegative(money))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        }

        transactionCount = 0;
        transactionTotal = 0;
        purchasePrice = 0;
        registerMoney = Arrays.copyOf(money, money.length);

    }


    /**
     * @param money
     *            money has a negative integer.
     */
    private boolean moneyHasNegative(int[] money)
    {

        if (money.length != 5)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (money[0] < 0 || money[1] < 0 || money[2] < 0 || money[3] < 0
                || money[4] < 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (money[0] == 0 && money[1] == 0 && money[2] == 0 && money[3] == 0
                && money[4] == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    // ==========================================================
    // Public Accessor Methods
    // ==========================================================
    /**
     * Returns the purchase price. Returns 0 if a purchase has not begun yet.
     * 
     * @return purchase price.
     */

    public int getPrice()
    {
        return purchasePrice;
    }


    /**
     * @return the registerAmount
     */
    public int getRegisterAmount()
    {
        return registerMoney[0] * DOLLAR + registerMoney[1] * QUARTER
                + registerMoney[2] * DIME + registerMoney[3] * NICKEL
                + registerMoney[4] * PENNY;

    }


    /**
     * The value of payment amount multiplied by constants.
     */
    private int paymentAmountValue()
    {
        return paymentMoney[0] * DOLLAR + paymentMoney[1] * QUARTER
                + paymentMoney[2] * DIME + paymentMoney[3] * NICKEL
                + paymentMoney[4] * PENNY;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * @return the amount of payment.
     */
    public int getPaymentAmount()
    {
        return this.paymentAmountValue();

    }


    /**
     * The value of change amount multiplied by constants.
     */
    private int changeAmountValue()
    {
        return changeMoney[0] * DOLLAR + changeMoney[1] * QUARTER
                + changeMoney[2] * DIME + changeMoney[3] * NICKEL
                + changeMoney[4] * PENNY;
    }


    /**
     * @return the change amount.
     */
    public int getChangeAmount()
    {
        return this.changeAmountValue();
    }


    /**
     * @return the register money as string.
     */
    public String getRegisterMoney()
    {
        return "Dollars: " + registerMoney[0] + "\n" + "Quarters: "
                + registerMoney[1] + "\n" + "Dimes: " + registerMoney[2] + "\n"
                + "Nickels: " + registerMoney[3] + "\n" + "Pennies: "
                + registerMoney[4] + "\n";

    }


    /**
     * get the payment money as a string.
     */
    private String paymentMoneyString()
    {
        return "Dollars: " + paymentMoney[0] + "\n" + "Quarters: "
                + paymentMoney[1] + "\n" + "Dimes: " + paymentMoney[2] + "\n"
                + "Nickels: " + paymentMoney[3] + "\n" + "Pennies: "
                + paymentMoney[4] + "\n";
    }


    /**
     * @return the payment money as a string.
     */
    public String getPaymentMoney()
    {
        return this.paymentMoneyString();

    }


    /**
     * The value of payment amount multiplied by constants.
     */
    private String changeMoneyString()
    {
        return "Dollars: " + changeMoney[0] + "\n" + "Quarters: "
                + changeMoney[1] + "\n" + "Dimes: " + changeMoney[2] + "\n"
                + "Nickels: " + changeMoney[3] + "\n" + "Pennies: "
                + changeMoney[4] + "\n";
    }


    /**
     * @return the change money as a string.
     */

    public String getChangeMoney()
    {
        return this.changeMoneyString();

    }


    /**
     * @return the transaction count.
     */
    public int getTransactionCount()
    {
        return transactionCount;

    }


    /**
     * @return the transaction in total.
     */
    public int getTransactionTotal()
    {
        return transactionTotal;

    }


    // ==========================================================
    // Public Mutator Methods
    // ==========================================================

    // Begins a transaction using the specified price.
    // If a transaction is already in progress, throws an IllegalStateException
    // If the specified price is not positive, throws an
    // IllegalArgumentException
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Begins a transaction using the specified price.
     * 
     * @param price
     *            the price of the item
     */
    public void beginPurchase(int price)
    {
        if (transactionAlreadyInProgress())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        if (price <= 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        purchasePrice = price;
    }


    /**
     * shows that the transaction is already in progress.
     */
    private boolean transactionAlreadyInProgress()
    {

        return false;
    }


    // Records the specified payment.
    // If the purchase has not begun yet, throws IllegalStateException
    // If the specified money array is not valid (see the constructor),
    // throws IllegalArgumentException
    // If the amount of money given is not sufficient to cover the
    // purchase price, the transaction is canceled.

    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Records the specified payment.
     * 
     * @param money
     *            payment money
     */
    public void enterPayment(int[] money)
    {

        if (purchaseHasNotBegunYet())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        if (this.notValidMoneyArray(money))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (money[0] != purchasePrice || money[1] != purchasePrice
                    || money[2] != purchasePrice || money[3] != purchasePrice
                    || money[4] != purchasePrice)
                break;
        }

        paymentMoney = Arrays.copyOf(money, money.length);
    }


    /**
     * purchase has not begun. Purchase will be canceled if true.
     */
    private boolean purchaseHasNotBegunYet()
    {
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * If money array or length is not valid, it will return false.
     */

    private boolean notValidMoneyArray(int[] money)

    {
        if (money.length != 5)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (money[0] < 0 || money[1] < 0 || money[2] < 0 || money[3] < 0
                || money[4] < 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (money[0] == 0 && money[1] == 0 && money[2] == 0 && money[3] == 0
                && money[4] == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        {
            return false;
        }

    }


    // Calculates the change due to the customer using the largest bill
    // and coin denominations first. Thus, the change given will use the
    // maximum amount of dollars, then the maximum amount of quarters,
    // then dimes, then nickels, then pennies. For example, if the change
    // required is $15.84, the change will be 15 dollars, 3 quarters,
    // 1 nickel, and 4 pennies. It will NOT be 12 dollars, 8 quarters,
    // 10 dimes, 12 nickels and 24 pennies. If payment has not been entered
    // yet, throws IllegalStateException.

    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * throws out the calculated change.
     * 
     * @param money
     *            changeMoney
     */
    public void calculateChange()
    {
        int changeToGiveBack = 1299;

        int dollarsToGiveBack = 0;

        int quartersToGiveBack = 0;

        int dimesToGiveBack = 0;

        int nickelsToGiveBack = 0;

        int penniesToGiveBack = 0;

        changeMoney[0] = dollarsToGiveBack;
        changeMoney[1] = quartersToGiveBack;
        changeMoney[2] = dimesToGiveBack;
        changeMoney[3] = nickelsToGiveBack;
        changeMoney[4] = penniesToGiveBack;

        while (changeToGiveBack >= DOLLAR)
        { // check if >= works better or worse than >
            changeMoney[0] = changeMoney[0] + 1;
            changeToGiveBack = changeToGiveBack - DOLLAR;
        }
        while (changeToGiveBack >= QUARTER)
        {
            changeMoney[1] = changeMoney[1] + 1;
            changeToGiveBack = changeToGiveBack - QUARTER;
        }

        while (changeToGiveBack >= DIME)
        {
            changeMoney[2] = changeMoney[2] + 1;
            changeToGiveBack = changeToGiveBack - DIME;
        }

        while (changeToGiveBack >= NICKEL)
        {
            changeMoney[3] = changeMoney[3] + 1;
            changeToGiveBack = changeToGiveBack - NICKEL;
        }
        while (changeToGiveBack >= PENNY)
        {
            changeMoney[4] = changeMoney[4] + 1;
            changeToGiveBack = changeToGiveBack - PENNY;
        }

        if (paymentNotBeenEntered())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

    }


    // Completes the transaction. Money in cash register is updated.
    // The price, payment, and change all become 0. The transaction count
    // is incremented and the total amount of money made in all transactions
    // is updated. If the cashier does not have enough money to give change
    // in the EXACT way it was calculated, the transaction is cancelled -
    // the item is not purchased, and the customer gets their exact coins back.
    // The amount and type of money in the register is unchanged from before
    // the transaction began. If change has not been calculated yet,
    // throws IllegalStateException

    private boolean paymentNotBeenEntered()
    {
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Completes the transaction.
     * 
     * @param money
     *            complete purchase money
     */
    public void completePurchase()
    {


    }




    // ==========================================================
    // Public Static Methods
    // ==========================================================

    // Returns a string for the specified amount with a dollar sign
    // at the beginning and a decimal two places from the end.
    // For example, the amount 10538 cents becomes the string $105.38.
    // No commas are printed in the string.
    // public static String prettyPrint(int amount) { }


    // ==========================================================
    // Private Methods
    // ==========================================================

    // In this project you WILL have private methods. If you do not,
    // it means you have redundant code in your class and the grader
    // will take off points for it.
}





    This is the part where CashregisterTest begins.


     > public class CashRegisterTest
    {

        private CashRegister cr;


        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * throws an Exception
         * 
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Before
        public void setUp()
                throws Exception
        {
            cr = new CashRegister(new int[] { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 });
        }


        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Testing the Constructors
         */
        // ==========================================================
        // Constructor Tests
        // ==========================================================

        @Test
        public void testConstructor()
        {

            assertEquals(2820, cr.getRegisterAmount());

            cr.beginPurchase(1299);
            assertEquals(1299, cr.getPrice());

            int[] paymentMoney = { 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            cr.enterPayment(paymentMoney);
            assertEquals(paymentMoney, cr.getPaymentAmount());

            cr.calculateChange();
            assertEquals(1288, cr.getChangeAmount());

            assertEquals(0, cr.getChangeAmount());

            assertEquals(0, cr.getTransactionCount());

            assertEquals(0, cr.getTransactionTotal());
        }


        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Checks if constructor throws an illegal argument exception when array !=
         * 5.
         */
        // This test method checks that the constructor
        // correctly throws an illegal argument exception when
        // the array has a length other than five

        @Test(
                expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
        public void testConstructorArrayBadLength()
        {
            int[] money = { 20, 20, 20, 20 }; // bad parameter; only has length four
            cr = new CashRegister(money); // this should throw an exception
            fail(); // if we reach here, our constructor is wrong
        }


        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Test if the constructor throws illegal argument exception if array
         * contains a negative integer.
         */
        // Write a test method that checks if the constructor
        // correctly throws an illegal argument exception when
        // the array argument contains a negative integer

        @Test(
                expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
        public void testConstructorArrayNegativeLength()
        {

            int[] money = { -20, 20, 20, 20, 20 }; // bad parameter; only has
    // length
    // four
            cr = new CashRegister(money); // this should throw an exception
            fail(); // if we reach here, our constructor is wrong
        }


        // Write a test method that checks if the constructor
        // correctly throws an illegal argument exception when
        // the array argument contains all zeros

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Tests if the constructor correctly throws an illegal argument Exception
         * when array = 0.
         * 
         * @Test IllegalArgumentException
         */
        @Test(
                expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
        public void testConstructorArrayAllZeros()
        {

            int[] money = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // bad parameter; only has length four
            cr = new CashRegister(money); // this should throw an exception
            fail(); // if we reach here, our constructor is wrong
        }


        // ==========================================================
        // Accessor Tests
        // ==========================================================

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Dont know yet
         */
        @Test
        public void testGetMoney()
        {
            // getRegisterMoney
            // getPaymentMoney
            // getChangeMoney
            String registerMoney =
                    "Dollars: 20\n" + "Quarters: 20\n" + "Dimes: 20\n"
                            + "Nickels: 20\n" + "Pennies: 20\n";
            String zeroMoney =
                    "Dollars: 0\n" + "Quarters: 0\n" + "Dimes: 0\n"
                            + "Nickels: 0\n" + "Pennies: 0\n";
            assertEquals(registerMoney, cr.getRegisterMoney());
            assertEquals(zeroMoney, cr.getPaymentMoney());
            assertEquals(zeroMoney, cr.getChangeMoney());
        }


        // ==========================================================
        // Mutator Tests
        // ==========================================================

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Place a description of your method here.
         */

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Sunny day not yet
         */
        @Test
        public void testSunnyDay()
        {
            System.out.println(cr.getRegisterMoney());

            cr.beginPurchase(1800);
            assertEquals(1800, cr.getPrice());

            int[] paymentMoney = { 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            cr.enterPayment(paymentMoney);
            System.out.println(cr.getPaymentMoney());
            cr.calculateChange();
            System.out.println(cr.getChangeMoney());

            // cr.completePurchase();

            System.out.println(cr.getRegisterMoney());

            String registerMoney =
                    "Dollars: 20\n" + "Quarters: 20\n" + "Dimes: 20\n"
                            + "Nickels: 20\n" + "Pennies: 20\n";
            assertEquals(registerMoney, cr.getRegisterMoney());
        }

        // ==========================================================
        // Static Method Tests
        // ==========================================================

    }
```

Comment: For the pretty-print method, look into Java floating point numbers, so you can divide by 100 and get the decimal point amount, and System.out.printf(). It has ways of specifying how many decimal places to show when printing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you need help with?

Comment: @AndrewRegan I have no idea what to do with the completePurchase() method. I tried to substitute the purchasePrice from paymentMoney but it does not work, since paymentMoney is an array and purchasePrice an integer. Additionally the instructors wants me to update the total amount of money in all transactions. How do I do this?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson thank you. I will try it.

Comment: @AndrewRegan Basically this is what he wants me to do:  Money in cash register is updated. The price, payment, and change all become 0. The transaction count is incremented and the total amount of money made in all transactions is updated. If the cashier does not have enough money to give change in the EXACT way it was calculated, the transaction is cancelled - the item is not purchased, and the customer gets their exact coins back.The amount and type of money in the register is unchanged from before the transaction began.If change has not been calculated yet  throws IllegalStateException

Comment: not sure what you need for the complete purchase. Can you clarify what should be happening? Pretty print is easy though.

Comment: @JordanSeanor There are 4 different public void methods. In the first void method the purchase begins. The second void method records the specified payment. The third void method calculates the change. And the last void method, which is completePurchase, need to complete the transaction. I think a calculation is needed. But I am not sure. 
 
Suppose you have the following transaction:
 
cash register has one quarter (nothing else)
price is $2.75
payment is 4 dollar bills
change due is 1 dollar bill and 1 quarter. So I have to give the customer 1 Dollar plus the quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**completePurchase**:

> If change has not been calculated yet throws IllegalStateException

That's easy enough to check, I'll leave that to you.

> If the cashier does not have enough money to give change in the EXACT way it was calculated, the transaction is cancelled - the item is not purchased, and the customer gets their exact coins back.

Iterate through each type of coin, and subtract the amount in change from the amount in the registers. If any go below zero, then give the customer back their money.

```
for (int x = 0; x < registerMoney.length; x++)
    if (registerMoney[x] - changeMoney[x] < 0)
        // GIVE ME BACK MY MONEY!
```

If you make it past here, then there is enough change of each type in the register, so go ahead with the transaction.

> Money in cash register is updated.

```
for (int x = 0; x < registerMoney.length; x++)
    registerMoney[x] -= changeMoney[x];
```

> The price, payment, and change all become 0. The transaction count is incremented and the total amount of money made in all transactions is updated.

This is fairly straight-forward Java stuff. You can fill the paymentMoney and changeMoney arrays with zero like so:

```
Arrays.fill(array, 0);
```

And that's all there is to it! I hope that helps.

By the way, your instructor is teaching you bad habits. *Other classes should not have to know about the internal state of a cash register in order to make a purchase*; they should just be able to call the method 'Purchase' and have everything happen in one go.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it will help me a lot. I am a rookie in Java, so sorry for not letting you exactly know what is required in this project. 
I have one last question: How do I update the total amount of money made in all transactions? What do I need to do here?

Comment: Similar to the line with `registerMoney[x] -= changeMoney[x];`, except this time you want to _add_ to the total money made, so `total += changeMoney[x];` (With the same for-each line above).